# Relation compositions, subsets question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$;$ means relation composition.

I need to prove the following:

Given two endorelations $R$ and $S$ such that $R; S\subseteq S ; R^+$, prove that $R^+ ; S\subseteq S ; R^+$

I tried the following:

Assume $R ; S\subseteq S; R^+$

Take $(x,y)$ such that $x(R^+; S)y$

Take $z$ such that $xR^+z$ and $zSy$

$\vdots$

$x(S; R^+)y$

$R^+; S\subseteq S; R^+$

I have no idea what to fill in on the dots.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is almost impossible to read.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Could you include in the question the meaning of $R+$ for a relation $R$ ? Also I assume by "endorelations" is meant simply relations all from a single set to itself, is that right?

Comment: @coffeemath, my guess is that $R^+$ is likely transitive closure, and an endorelation is indeed a relation from a set to itself.

Comment: The author of the text you're following is trying a bit too hard to be original. Who uses $;$ to denote $\circ$?

Comment: @GitGud: I have no idea, but I just replaced them all.

Comment: oh thanks for formatting my post. the reason behind ; to ∘ is that r∘s =/= s∘r, so he didn't like a symetric symbol... and R+ is indeed transitive closure

Comment: @GitGud This is actually a fairly common notation, especially in theoretical computer science. The idea is that $f;g$ (for functions) is composition in left-to-right diagrammatic order (first apply $f$, then apply $g$) which is opposite to the Leibnizian order where we would write $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$.

Comment: @user43208 A gut feeling told me it had to be a notation from something like computer science. Thanks.

Comment: OK, semicolons put back. Sorry.

Comment: @BillDubuque Haha thanks for you concern and kindness. I had no problem with your comment, but do appreciate your thoughtfulness. Until next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can argue like this. Let $X$ be the domain of discourse (so that $R, S$ are relations from $X$ to itself). First, $R^+ = \bigvee_{n \geq 1} R^n$. A key fact is that composition on either side with a relation $S$ preserves joins, because (for example) composition $- ; S: \text{Endo}(X) \to \text{Endo}(X)$ has a right adjoint. Let's calculate: $R;S \leq T$ iff for all $x, z$, $\exists_y x R y \wedge y S z$ implies $x T z$, iff for all $x, y$, $x R y$ implies $\forall_z y S z \Rightarrow x T z$, iff $R \leq S\backslash T$ where the right side is defined by the formula $x S\backslash T y := \forall_z y S z \Rightarrow x T z$. This shows $-; S$ is left adjoint to $S \backslash -$.

Thus we have $R^+ ;S = (\bigvee_{n \geq 1} R^n) ; S = \bigvee_{n \geq 1} (R^n ; S)$. So to show $R^+ ; S \leq S ; R^+$, we just have to show that $R^n ; S \leq S ; R^+$ for all $n$. This can be done by induction. The case $n = 1$ is just what we assumed at the outset. Then, given $R^{n-1}; S \leq S; R^+$, we have

$$R^n ; S = R ; R^{n-1} ; S \leq R ; S ; R^+ \leq S ; R^+ ; R^+ \leq S ; R^+$$

where the first inequality is the inductive hypothesis, the second is the assumption, and the third just says $R^+$ is transitive.

(I reverted back to $;$ instead of $\circ$. It makes no essential difference to the structure of the argument.)

Comment: woh thanks man this makes sense. It never occurred to me to use an induction proof here but it makes so much sense given the definition of $R^+$. Thanks a lot this was really bugging me:p

Comment: Wasn't sure you already knew the technique of adjoints, but glad it helped.